# javascript - remove extra spaces before given characters

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters, str-replace

I have this function, which adds an extra spaces after comma.

```
 function fixString1(inp){
    var i, len, arr, outp, Rside, Lside, RsideIsNum, LsideIsNum;

    arr = inp.split(",");
    outp = "";

    for(i=1, len=arr.length; i<len; i++){
        Lside = arr[i-1];
        Rside = arr[i];

        LsideIsNum = /\d/.test(Lside.charAt(Lside.length-1));
        RsideIsNum = /\d/.test(Rside.charAt(0));

        outp += "," + ((LsideIsNum && RsideIsNum)?"":" ") + Rside;
    }

    return (arr[0] + outp).replace(/ {2,}/g, " ");
}
```

How can it modify to apply more than one character, I mean I want to apply this function besides comma to `. ! ? :` chars too.

Anyone know how to solve?

Comment: You can probably do the whole thing with a simple regular expression replacement. You need to describe a little better what *exactly* you want to do to the input string.

Comment: You should provide some example input and expected outputs.

Comment: OK well see my answer then. I think you mean that you want numbers to come out like "123,456" and otherwise like "hello, world".

Comment: @Pointy yes, you are right
This function is working very well, only removes spaces before commas

Comment: Your function does not remove space before commas, it's actually the opposite, it adds a space after commas... Have you tested it? Hard to help if you don't understand your own code.

Comment: @wared you are right, I made a mistake, this function put a space after comma. I corrected this, but my question was, modify this function, to ADD SPACE after another kind of chars. Thank you for correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more parameter to the function declaration which indicates the character. If you want to run the function only once then you can provide a set of the characters in the split function e.g. `inp.split(".,'")`

Comment: Not a very good solution if OP has to do the same for 10 special characters.

Comment: I want to call this function only once, if it is possible.

Comment: I call the function for every char, like fixString1(inp,specialchar), and I have modified the function in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you want to do, but I think you can do it much more concisely:

```
function fixString1( inp ) {
  return inp.replace(/(\d)\s+([,!?:.])\s*(\d)/g, "$1$2$3")
    .replace(/\s*([,!?:.])\s+/g, "$1 ");
}
```

The first regular expression looks for digits on either side of a special character, with intervening space on the left and possibly intervening space on the right. It replaces that with the two digits and the special character, and no spaces.

The second regular expression deals with all the other spaces around the special characters. It gets rid of all such spaces and makes sure there's one space following the special character.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without regular expression.
[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/thxp3/3/)

```
var str = "    a   a    givi , asdad , saba  a   .  sdada! hasdjahj    ?  asdas asd as   luka    ,      ";

function fixString(str) {
    var temp = "",
        count = 0;
    str.split("").forEach(function (value, index, array) {
        var next = array[index + 1],
            x = value.charCodeAt(),
            isChar = ((x >= 65 && x <= 90) || (x >= 97 && x <= 122));
        if (value === " ") {
            count++;
        } else if (count > 0 && value !== " ") {
            temp += ((next && next !== " ") || (temp.length > 0 && isChar) ? " " : "") + value;
            count = 0;
        } else {
            temp += value;
        }
    });
    return temp;
}
console.log(fixString(str));
```